# Kivy updating a widget image from outside the function that calls the layout

Tags: python, image, layout, scope, kivy

I have a function scope issue. I need to update 'cardTableLayout' when the 'discard' button is pressed, after the evaluate function is called. How do I do this? I know this is a kv layout language issue. I'm not sure how to refrence 'cardTableLayout' from inside 'buttonClick_callback.'
python code

```
import sys
from os import path, listdir
from random import choice
sys.path.append('libs')
from good_deal import *
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ToggleButtonBehavior  
from kivy.clock import mainthread
randomSong = choice(listdir('music'))
backgroundMusic = SoundLoader.load(path.join('music', randomSong))
backgroundMusic.play()
backgroundMusic.loop = True
cardImagesGlobal = []
hand, deck = deal()
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager): pass
class Card(ToggleButtonBehavior, Image): pass
class GameButton(Button): pass
def buttonClick_callback(self):
    buttonClickSound = SoundLoader.load(path.join('sounds', 'buttonClick.ogg'))
    buttonClickSound.play()
    index = 0 
    for items in cardImagesGlobal:
        if items.state == 'down':
            hand.marked.append(index)
            index += 1
    discard(hand, deck)
    evaluate(hand)
class CardTableScreen(Screen):
    @mainthread
    def on_enter(self):
        global cardImagesGlobal
        cardImages = []
        self.ids['handType'].text = hand.type
        index = 0
        for items in hand.ordered:
            cardImages.append(Card(source = hand.filenames[index]))
            self.ids['handLayout'].add_widget(cardImages[index])
            index += 1
        cardImagesGlobal = cardImages
        discardButton = GameButton(text = 'DISCARD')
        discardButton.bind(on_press = buttonClick_callback)
        self.ids['cardTableLayout'].add_widget(discardButton)
layoutFile = Builder.load_file('main.kv')
class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Good Deal Poker'
        return layoutFile
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

kv File

```
ScreenManagement:
    CardTableScreen:
<Card>:
    size_hint: (.95, .95)
<GameButton>:
    size_hint: (.20, .10)
<CardTableScreen>:
    name: 'cardTableScreen'
    FloatLayout:
        name: 'cardTableLayout'
        id: cardTableLayout
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0,.25,0,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            name: 'handType'
            id: handType
            font_size: '20sp'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.95}
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: (1, .30)
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.75}
            name: 'handLayout'
            id: handLayout
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,.25,0,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
```

Answer (score 0):

The button has been added to the `cardTableLayout`. On press, it executes a function called `buttonClick_callback`, passing itself as the first parameter.

This allows to reference the `cardTableLayout` inside the `buttonClick_callback` by calling `self.parent`.

Comment: I know that self.parent should give me access to the widgets in the parent function, however, I still cannot access the widget tree via the ids or name keys in the kv file. print(self.parent.ids) returns '[]'. Additionally, self.parent.ask_update() does nothing. neither does self.parent.do_layout(). What I need to do is update the canvas for each widget in the layout.

Comment: @SteveHostetler What is written in the console when you do `print(self.parent)` or `print(self)` in the `buttonClick_callback`? Is the result correct? If it is, can you iterate over children list, and display their names, like `names = [c.name for c in self.parent.children]`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the good_deal lib that was imported. The values being passed in were not updating correctly. Once rectified, the canvas is updating correctly.